# Mailchimp template issue while using repeatable blocks

Tags: javascript, php, templates, block, mailchimp

I have created form template in Mailchimp, I have been through the documentation and using all the Mailchimp tags respectively its even showing me the icons to drag/ movable content editable etc.

Whenever I edit the content its visible through the campaign test area but when i copy the block and change the positioning, it changes its position in the backend but do not show any changes on the campaign test area.

Here is some piece of the html i am using, i have checked the html for issue but i am unable to find any issues.

```
<tr mc:repeatable="ntwologo" mc:variant="new-layout-twologo">
    <td mc:hideable align="center" valign="top" class="fix-box">
         <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">

           <!-- start layout-3 container width 600px --> 
           <table width="600" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="container" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: #ffffff; ">
             <tr>
               <td valign="top">

                 <!-- start layout-3 container width 560px --> 
                 <table width="560" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color:#ffffff;">


                   <!--start space height --> 
                   <tr>
                     <td height="20"></td>
                   </tr>
                   <!--end space height --> 

                   <!-- start image content --> 
                   <tr>
                     <td valign="top" width="100%">                      

                       <table class="full-width">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="heading" style="margin-bottom:20px;" mc:edit="text heading">
                                        Most Active Canadian
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="twologos">
                                    <img mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" style="border:1px solid #b5ae92;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/85ff5a532432ef3d1b871c206/images/dceb568a-6e4c-48b8-a2b7-1db04b6780d8.jpg" mc:edit="layoutleftlogo">
                                    <img mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" style="border:1px solid #b5ae92;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/85ff5a532432ef3d1b871c206/images/f1eb0308-e0ad-4f6e-b15c-e5583f72a4cf.jpg" mc:edit="layoutrightlogo">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="yaletext" mc:edit="text content">
                                        <!-- text here -->
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="#" class="readmorelink">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                       </table> 
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <!-- end image content --> 

                 </table>
                 <!-- end layout-3 container width 560px --> 
               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
           <!-- end layout-3 container width 600px --> 
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <!-- END LAYOUT-3  -->
```

Comment: Got what the problem was, it was happening due to cache on mailchimp.
maybe the info i am writing is helpful to someone because i was unable to find out this anywhere that mailchimp may cause problem due to cache.
Thanks by the way.